# Field 'translatableResources' doesn't exist on type 'QueryRoot'

Tags: graphql, shopify

I installed the [Shopify GraphiQL App](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api/graphiql-app) in my Shopify store to test some GraphQL queries.

I want to translate content via their API.
Here is the documentation for it: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/multi-language/translating-content-api#retrieve-a-list-of-translatable-resource-types

Now, I want to query their first example in the documentation: `Retrieve a list of translatable resource types`

```
{
  __type(name: "TranslatableResourceType") {
    enumValues {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

And received this response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "__type": null
  }
}
```

Also the second query isn't working: `Retrieve a list of translatable resources by their type`

```
{
  translatableResources(first: 1, resourceType: PRODUCT) {
    edges {
      node {
        resourceId
        translatableContent {
          key
          value
          digest
          locale
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error of the second query:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Field 'translatableResources' doesn't exist on type 'QueryRoot'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "query",
        "translatableResources"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "undefinedField",
        "typeName": "QueryRoot",
        "fieldName": "translatableResources"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I installed the Shopify GraphiQL App, I picked all permissions (incl. `read_translations` and `write_translations` permissions).
And I do have products in my store.

Which setting is missing or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, you have to pick the `unstable` API version. Now it's possible to execute the queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using either 2019-07 or 2019-10, you need to use unstable version where shopify added translatableResources Queryroot. Please check below image:

[image]

Comment: That was indeed the fix! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using POSTMAN or INSOMNIA for testing then the URL will be:

`https://{{store}}.myshopify.com/admin/api/unstable/graphql.json`

Before using the unstable version, you need to change the private app version to Unstable.

[image: Private App version]